# Find UMVUE of $6\theta^2$ given $f(x\mid\theta) = \frac{1}{2\theta^2} e^{\frac{-\sqrt{x}}{\theta}} I_{(0,\infty)}(x)$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Given $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d  rvs with pdf $f(x\mid\theta) = \frac{1}{2\theta^2} e^{\frac{-\sqrt{x}}{\theta}} I_{(0,\infty)}(x)$  for $\ \theta > 0$.

(a) Find the UMVUE of $\ 6\theta^2$, and the variance of UMVUE.

(b) Find the CRLB of the UMVUE

(c) Find the variance of MME of $6\theta^2$ based on first moment.

**My thought:** For part (a), I got the same answer using Lehmann-Scheffer theorem as that of **NCh's** answer below. I would now present my computation for variance of UMVUE $= \frac{3}{2n^2+n} (\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{X_i})^2$.

We have: $Var(\frac{3}{2n^2+n} (\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{X_i})^2) = \frac{9}{(2n^2+n)^2} (E(Z^4) - E^2(Z^2))$  where $Z = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{X_i}$. Now, $E(Z^2) = \theta^2(4n^2+2n)$. In addition, $Z$ is the sum of $n$ i.i.d r.vs which follow $N(\ 2n\theta, \ 2n\theta^2)$, so $E(Z^4) = (2n\theta)^4 + 6(2n\theta)^2(2n\theta^2)^2 + 3(2n\theta^2)^4$.

Thus, $\frac{9}{(2n^2+n)^2} (E(Z^4) - E^2(Z^2)) = \frac{9}{(2n^2+n)^2} (16n^4\theta^4 + 96n^4\theta^6 + 48\theta^8n^4 - 16n^4\theta^4 - 16n^3\theta^4 - 4n^2\theta^4)$

(b) To find the CRLB, I need first to verify $\ E\ (\overline{X}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\log f(\overline{X}\mid\theta)) = 12\theta,$ as $\overline{X}$ is an unbiased estimator of $6\theta$. Now, $\log f(\overline{X}\mid\theta) = \frac{-\sqrt{\overline{X}}}{\theta} - \log{2\theta^2}$, so $E\ (\overline{X}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\log f(\overline{X}\mid\theta)) = E(\frac{\overline{X}^{3/2} - 2\theta\overline{X}}{\theta^2}) = -12\theta + \frac{1}{\theta^2}E(\overline{X}^{3/2}).$ But I got stuck here since I cannot compute $\ E(\overline{X}^{3/2})$.

(c) The MME of $6\theta^2$ based on first moment is $\overline{X}$. Thus, we only need to compute $Var(\overline{X}) = \frac{Var(X_1)}{n} = \fbox{$\frac{84\theta^4}{n}$}$ (since $E(X^2) = 120\theta^4$)

**My question:** Could someone please help with parts (a) and (b) above? Also, is my answer for part (c) correct?

Comment: If $\operatorname{E}(X_1) = 6\theta^2$ and if $\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{X_i}$ is a complete sufficient statistic, then $\operatorname{E}(X_1\mid \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{X_i}\,)$ is the UMVUE of $6\theta^2.$ At this moment I'm not sure how to evaluate that.

Comment: That's correct by Rao-Blackwell Theorem. I also got to that, but then I did not know how to compute that conditional expectation either:(

Comment: The set $\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x_i} = \text{constant}$ is an $(n-1)$-dimensional manifold and it is compact and is a subset of $[0,\,\text{constant}^2]^n.$ The density is constant on that manifold. So you're looking for the average value of $x_1$ on that manifold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no need to compute conditional expectations. Let $$T=\overline{\sqrt{X}}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{X_i}}{n}$$
You have already found its expectation:
$$\mathbb ET=\mathbb E\sqrt{X_1}=2\theta.$$
Let us find UMVUE of $6\theta^2$ as $\theta^*=c(n)T^2$. Firstly find $\mathbb E T^2$:
$$
\mathbb ET^2 = \text{Var}\,T+\left(\mathbb ET\right)^2 = \frac{\text{Var}\sqrt{X_1}}{n}+4\theta^2=\frac{\mathbb EX_1-4\theta^2}{n}+4\theta^2 = \frac{2\theta^2}{n}+4\theta^2.
$$ 
And if we take $$
c(n) = \frac{6}{\frac2n+4}=\frac{3n}{1+2n}$$
we'll obtain the desired result: 
$$
\mathbb E\theta^* = \mathbb E\left(\frac{6}{\frac2n+4}T^2\right) = \frac{6}{\frac2n+4} \times \left(\frac{2\theta^2}{n}+4\theta^2\right)=6\theta^2.
$$
And $\theta^*$ is UMVUE since it is a function of complete sufficient statistics.

Comment: thank you so much!! It mached my answer for the first half of part (a), but I'm using Lehmman-Scheffe's theorem instead. However, to compute the variance of $\theta^{*}$, I would need to compute $E(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{X_i})^4)$. To do this, I plan to let $Z = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{X_i}$, which follows $N(2n\theta, 2n\theta^2)$. Thus $E(Z^4) = 4$-th moment of $Z$ $= 16n^4\theta^4+ 96n^4\theta^6 + 48n^4\theta^8$. Thus, $Var(\theta*)  = \frac{9}{(2n^2+n)}^2 (   6n^4\theta^4+ 96n^4\theta^6 + 48n^4\theta^8 - \theta^4(4n^2+2n)^2)$. Could you help verify if my step above is correct?

Comment: @user177196 $\sqrt{X_i}$ does not follow normal distribution. It is so-called Rayleigh distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution

Comment: Thanks a ton. But then I'm clueless on computing $E(Z^4)$:((

Comment: @user177196 Oh, sure it is not Rayleigh: the power of exponent is not $x^2$, but only $x$. For example, you can write 4th power using multinomial theorem and calculate moments of summands. You can also find how the ratio $\sqrt{X_i}/\theta$ is distributed and then use wide-known properties if this distribution.

Comment: Seriously?? I have to expand all those $n$ variables out and compute each of them? Could you please show me a better way, as the other one is too much to compute, I think:((

Comment: @user177196 Look at the second part of the previous comment.

Comment: what are those properties?? I don't know what is the distribution of $\frac{\sqrt{X_i}}{\theta}$ even though I have mean and variance. Could you show me how you woukd solve it?

Comment: @user177196 Try to find this distribution. Do you know this formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables ?

Comment: thanks so much for your hint. Using the *chain-rule* formula in the link, we have: $f_{Y}(y) = \frac{y}{\theta^2}e^{-\frac{y}{\theta}}$ for $y > 0$. Now, let $Z= Y_1+\ldots + Y_n$, then $f_Z(y) = (f_{Y_1}(y))^n$ (since $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ are i.i.d) so $f_Z(z) = \frac{z^n}{\theta^{2n}}e^{\frac{-nz}{\theta}}$. Now I could compute $E(z^4) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n+4}}{\theta^{2n}}e^{\frac{-nz}{\theta}}$. Is this correct?

Comment: @user177196 No. The p.d.f. of $\sqrt{X_i}/\theta$ should not depend on $\theta$. Moreover, the p.d.f. of the sum of i.i.d.r.v. does not equal to the product of p.d.f.'s. Find the p.d.f. correctly and recognize what distribution you got.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. It appears that the pdf of $\sqrt{X_i}/{\theta} = xe^{-\sqrt{x}}$, so it's a Weibull distribution. But the sum of i.i.d Weibull random variables  = ?? Remember, we need $E(\sum_{i=1}^{n}
 \sqrt{X_i})^4$

Comment: No. Try again. Did you forget to put $x^2$ in the power?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's a typo. It should be $xe^{-x}$, but it's a Weilbull distribution. I reviewed my work carefully, so I don't think I made a mistake this time.

Comment: can you just show me how you go from $E(\sqrt{X_i}/\theta)$ to $E((\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{X_i})^4)$? Because I ended up having some weird distributions like Weibull that has no nice closed-form formula to compute for the mean of this;p

Comment: $xe^{-x}$ is a pdf of Gamma distribution (use parametrization from Wiki) $\Gamma(\alpha,\beta)=\Gamma(2,1)$. Sum of independent r.v. with this distribution also has Gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha=2n, \beta=1$ and the pdf: $$\frac{1}{(2n-1)!}x^{2n-1}e^{-x}$$. Its 4th moment equals $$\frac{\Gamma(2n+4)}{\Gamma(2n)}=\frac{(2n+3)!}{(2n-1)!}.$$

Comment: I am so dumbbbb. Thank you so much for your patience!!

Comment: did you compute the explicit answer for variance? I got a horrible looking $\frac{36\theta^4}{n(2n+1)}(4n+3)$

Comment: @user177196 Yes, I got the same. It is not so horrible: lower Cramer - Rao bound for variance of unbiased estimators of $6\theta^2$ equals to $\frac{72\theta^4}{n}$. Our variance is slightly higher (since $\frac{4n+3}{2n+1}>2$) and asymptotically the same as this CRLB.