# Compute UMVUE of $\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Given $X_1,\ldots, X_7$ are i.i.d r.vs which follow $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

(a) Find the UMVUE of $\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}$.

(b) Compute variance of UMVUE in part (a)

(c) Find the lower bound of the variance of unbiased estimator of $\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}$ for $n$ i.i.d variables $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$ follows $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

**My thought:** First, we realize that $E(S^2) = \sigma^2$ where $S^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{7} (X_i - \overline{X})^2}{6}$ is a sample variance. Thus, $E(\frac{1}{S^2}) = \frac{A}{\sigma^2}$ (I could not see how to compute this constant $A$). Since the sample mean and sample variance of $X_1,\ldots, X_7$ are independent, we have: $E(\frac{\overline{X}}{S^2}) = E(\overline{X})E(\frac{1}{S^2}) = \frac{\mu}{A}$, so $\frac{\overline{X}}{AS^2}$ is the unbiased estimator of $\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}$.

Now, this unbiased estimator could be expressed as a complete sufficient statistics $(\sum_{i=1}^{7} X_i, \sum_{i=1}^{7} X_i^2)$ because $S^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{7} X_i^2 - \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{7} X_i)^2}{7}}{6}$. This implies $\fbox{$\frac{\overline{X}}{AS^2}$}$ is a UMVUE of $\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}$

(b) Thanks to the work by NCH below, we obtain UMVUE of $\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}$ is $\frac{2}{3} \frac{\overline{X}}{S^2}$. Thus, to compute $Var(\frac{\overline{X}}{S^2})$, we need to compute $E(\frac{\overline{X}^2}{S^4})$. First, since $\overline{X}$ and $\frac{1}{S^2}$ are independent, $\overline{X}^2$ and $\frac{1}{S^4}$ are independent. So $E(\frac{\overline{X}^2}{S^4}) = E(\overline{X}^2)E(\frac{1}{S^4})$. Now, since $Var(\overline{X}) = \frac{Var(X_1)}{7} = \frac{\sigma^2}{7}$, $E(\overline{X}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{7} + \mu^2$

**My question:** Could anyone please help me determine the constant $A$ above to complete this proof? I feel so shameful not to be able to compute $E(\frac{1}{S^2})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Cochran's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem), 
$$\frac{6S^2}{\sigma^2} =\sum_{i=1}^{7}\left(\frac{X_i-\overline{X}}{\sigma}\right)^2 \sim \chi^2_6$$

Denote this r.v. by $Z$.

The p.d.f. of $\chi^2_6$ equals to
$$
f_Z(x)=\frac{1}{2^3\Gamma(3)}x^{2} e^{-x/2}=\frac{1}{16}x^{2} e^{-x/2}, \ x>0
$$

Calculate 
$$
E\left(\frac1{S^2}\right)=E\left(\frac{\sigma^2}{6S^2}\cdot\frac{6}{\sigma^2}\right)=\frac{6}{\sigma^2}E\left(\frac{1}{Z}\right).
$$
$$
E\left(\frac{1}{Z}\right) = \int\limits_0^\infty \frac1x \frac{1}{16}x^{2} e^{-x/2}\, dx = \frac{1}{16}\int\limits_0^\infty x e^{-x/2}\, dx = \frac{4}{16}=\frac14.
$$
Finally, 
$$E\left(\frac1{S^2}\right)= \frac{6}{4\sigma^2}$$
and the constant $A=6/4=1.5$.

Comment: thanks a ton!! Could you help me on another problem here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212510/find-umvue-of-6-theta2-given-fxtheta-frac12-theta2-e-frac-sqr

Comment: could you also help on finding the variance of $\frac{2}{3} \frac{\overline{X}}{S^2}$, which is the UMVUE of $\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}$.

Comment: @user177196 If you know that $\overline X$ and $S^2$ are independent and the distributions of both values are also known, what prevents from calculating the variance? Find second moment $(4/9)E\left[\left(\overline X\right)^2\right]E\left[(1/S^2)^2\right]$.

Comment: thank you. I got how to do it right after I asked that dumb question:P Could you please try it to see if the variance is $\frac{9}{2\sigma^2}(1/7+\mu^2/2)$ since $E(1/S^4) = 9/(2\sigma^2)$, and $E(\overline{X}^2) = (\sigma^2/7+\mu^2)$?

Comment: @user177196 I got $E(1/S^4)=9/(2\sigma^4)$, the same second moment for $\overline X$ and final.variance $2/(7\sigma^2)+\mu^2/\sigma^4$.

Comment: thank you so much. I made a typo, but I forgot the factor $4/9$ at first. Your answer is quite useful. Now, for part (c), could you try using the information matrix $I(\theta) = (\frac{n}{\sigma^2}\ 0, 0\  \frac{n}{2\sigma^4})$ (notation means following by row of the matrix) and see if you get the lower bound as $\frac{\sigma^2+2\mu^2}{n\sigma^4}$. Please note that we are dealing with general $n$ for this part.

Comment: @user177196 Could **I** try? Do you want **me** to solve part (c) for you?

Comment: I solve it and got the bound above. Just want a confirmation if I did it correctly:)

Comment: @user177196 Very likely. I am not strong in the multidimensional Cramer-Rao.inequality and in changing variables in Fisher information. I got $I(\mu/\sigma^2) = n\sigma^2+n\sigma^4/(2\mu^2)$, but I doubt a lot.
And the answer for variance of UMVUE for general $n$ is much more complicated: $$\dfrac{(n-3)}{n(n-5)\sigma^2}+\dfrac{2\mu^2}{(n-5)\sigma^4}$$ which is true at least for $n=7$.

Comment: How did you get the $I(\mu/\theta^2)$ as a nunber?? It should be a vector, shouldn't it?

Comment: @user177196 $\mu/\sigma^2$ - this is a parameter that you have been estimating. And for UMVUE of this parameter you have found the lower bound of variance, is not it?.

Comment: yes, it's is. But what made me curious was that your $I(\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2})$ was very different from mine (I got $I(\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}) = (\frac{n}{\sigma^2} 0, 0 \frac{n}{2\sigma^4})$. I know you already said you doubted your result....

Comment: @user177196 The matrix you got is the Fisher information matrix for vector parameter $(\mu,\sigma^2)$. This is not the same as Fisher information for single parameter $\mu/\sigma^2$ which you obtained as $\frac{n\sigma^4}{\sigma^2+2\mu^2}$.

Comment: I see. My apology for misunderstanding. But we still got the different Fisher information then?

Comment: @user177196 Yes, but your answer looks preferable. If you can show how you obtained it, it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: The gradient of $\mu/\theta^2$ is $(\frac{1}{\theta^2}, \frac{-\mu}{\theta^4})'$, so the lower bound for the variance is $(1/\theta^2, \frac{-\mu}{\theta^4})[\frac{n}{\sigma^2} 0, 0 \frac{2\sigma^4}{n}] [\frac{1}{\sigma^2}, \frac{-\mu}{\sigma^4}] = \frac{\sigma^2+2\mu^2}{n\sigma^4}$ (vector * matrix*vector multiplication, where the matrix is in [row 1, row 2] format)

Comment: @user177196 Oh, yes! Thank you very much!